# How to map config in IConfigurationSection to a simple class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

Using MVC .net Core and building a concrete config class within the startup class.  My appsettings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "myconfig": {
    "other2": "tester,
    "other": "tester",
    "root": {
      "inner": {
        "someprop": "TEST VALUE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've represented this with a concrete class as follows:

```
public class TestConfig
{
    public string other2 { get; set; }
    public string other { get; set; }
    public Inner1 root { get; set; }
}

public class Inner1
{
    public Inner2 inner { get; set; }
}

public class Inner2
{
    public string someprop { get; set; }
}
```

And I can easily map this by doing the follow:

```
var testConfig = config.GetSection("myconfig").Get<TestConfig>();
```

However.... what I don't like about the above is the need to make TestConfig more complex than it needs to be.  Ideally, I'd like something like this:

```
public class PreciseConfig
{
    [Attribute("root:inner:someprop")]
    public string someprop { get; set; }
    public string other { get; set; }
    public string other2 { get; set; }
}
```

Where I don't have to have the nested objects within and can map directly to a lower property in this kind of way.  Is this possible? Using .net Core 2.1.

Thanks for any pointers in advance!

P.s. I know I can create an instance of PreciseConfig myself and set properties using `config.GetValue<string>("root:inner:someprop")` BUT I don't want to have to set all my custom settings in this way if I can do them automatically using a serialization property or similar.

Comment: Use the path `myconfig:root:inner` to get section and get `PreciseConfig`

Comment: I can create an instance of PreciseConfig myself and set values by getting the individual properties from config using config.get("root:inner:someprop") - however I don't want to do this one by one in code - if I can automatically do this using a mapping and just defining a property in the custom mapping that'd be better.

Comment: No. I meant `var testConfig = config.GetSection("myconfig:root:inner").Get<PreciseConfig>();`

Comment: Elaborated on why this wont work but giving a broader example (other properties in the root level that I need).

Comment: Ok that completely changes things.

Comment: I think I have figured it out. updating answer

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For the higher level config you get the configuration as normal with the top node.

Then use the path `myconfig:root:inner` to get the other desired section and Bind `PreciseConfig` from the previous step

```
var preciseConfig = config.GetSection("myconfig").Get<PreciseConfig>();

config.GetSection("myconfig:root:inner").Bind(preciseConfig);
```

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core : GetSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#getsection)

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core : Bind to an object graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#bind-to-an-object-graph)

Comment: I've expanded my example to show why I can't do this - I need properties mapped that are in "root".  So can't cut directly to inner.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi - I knew this could be done, I was just wondering if rather than multiple binds (say I have a couple of lower level properties) if this could be done in one go using some sort of serialization attribute to tell it where to look.  Thus doing all of the above in one go :-)

Comment: I have yet to come across such a thing in my experience with the framework so far.

Comment: @RobMcCabe Unless you write your own extension method to reduce it to what you desire

Comment: P.s. I did just that - wrote my own extension method - nuget can be found here:
https://github.com/rmccabe24/Cloud.Core.Extensions.Configuration - which allows you to then do `var myTypedInstance = config.BindBaseSection<AppSettings>();`